# Calling a function onKeyup event not working while pressing enter

Tags: javascript, html, enter, onkeyup

This is my code

```
function searchForProductsInPopup(evt) {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
     alert("in");
     if(charCode == 27) {
          closePopup();
     }
     else if(charCode == 13) {
          closePopup();
          return false;
     }
}
```

HTML code

```
<input type="text" 
       class="input-medium focused" 
       id="invoiceSearchKeyWord"
       onkeydown="return searchForProductsInPopup(event);"/>
```

This function will execute on the `keyup` event of a textbox, for all the other key my code will give an `alert` saying **in**. But when pressing `Enter` key I'm not getting any alerts and directly the form is submitted, why is that? My knowledge in `JS` is very limited. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Because a form has a `submit` event that doesn't get cancelled when you press enter - the default events and actions are still executing. Maybe do `event.preventDefault()` if `charCode === 13` to prevent it from sending the default submit event.

Comment: but @somethinghere the alert itself is not coming then how can I check that condition, I think it is never executing the function. I debugged in firefox, but execution is not happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `submit` event is triggered before your `keyup` event:

```
<form onsubmit="alert('submitted')">
    <input onkeyup="alert('keyup')"/>
</form>

1. submitted
2. Page navigates
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/pvw1dtb7/

You will see the expected `keyup` event if you properly prevent your `submit` event. Something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="alert('submitted'); event.preventDefault();">
    <input onkeyup="alert('keyup')"/>
</form>

1. submitted, event stopped
2. keyup
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/dmpxjt27/

Comment: so @Derek 朕會功夫 by adding **event.preventDefault();** I'm changing the nature of the form so that it won't submit when enter key is pressed right?

Comment: Yes, it prevents whatever the browser is going to do with that event by default.

Comment: but @Derek 朕會功夫, my form had a control of submit type (a submit button) whose click event is not working after adding **event.preventDefault();**, but instead of that if I keep a button and define  a function for form submission the form is submitting. Why is that?